# Сохранение ссылки href но переходить по ajax

Tags: javascript, html, css

Сделал ajax переход между страницами и подключил к нажатию тега , но нужно чтобы человек мог нажать на правую кнопку мыши и в меню открыть ее в другом окне. Если вставить href, то сначала выполняется ajax а потом переходит по ссылке. Нужно чтобы при клике переходило по ajax.
Надеюсь понятно объяснил...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вставить

```
return false;
```

в функцию клика.